# Acumatica : How to Adding watermark in a Reports using Source of Database

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone know how to add a watermark in a Reports using source of database?

i was try using picture box to test the database source and its work fine but if i want my image to be in the background it never works.

My picture box:

[image: My picture box]

Background:

[image: Background]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Report Designer does not support control overlays.

If you try to set the image behind another control you will find it highlights in red and won't show up when you use your report if both the image and the other control are visible.

This means you won't be able to setup a traditional watermark in the backround of the report, the most you could do for now is to locate the image someplace where it doesn't cross with any other control or where the other control is only visible when the image is invisible and vice versa.

Comment: I only able to get it to work with a Source of Embedded.
but if i use a Source of Embedded i can't make formula for my watermark.
if i want to manipulate the visibility, i can only use it for picturebox because if i used it for my watermark it will be disaster. I mean it will not work the way I want it to.
I like your advice about the location things so I will look for it.
Thanks Markoan